# How to mix global and local state in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I have a products page which `maps` through all products and foreach it displays the product image and a button 'add to cart'.

On add to cart click, I call a function from my redux actions. That function, sends an API request to the backend. While the call is in progress I wanna replace the add to cart button with a loader.

In my redux cart state, there is a boolean property `cartLoading` which is set to true at the start of the call and false once the call resolves. Here's the problem: if in my `EachProduct` component I bind the logic of weather or not to show a loader, to the value of `cartLoading` from the cart state, then whats happening is that all 'add to cart' buttons on the page are replaced with loaders since `cartLoading` is a global state property. But I also can not make loading a local state with `useState` because I have no way of knowing in the scope of the component weather the call to the backend has finished yet since its done by a global actions function.

I've tried to `subscribe` to the `store` and listen for a change in the `cartLoading` preperty when the button is clicked, but since I dont know in the component scope when the call is finish, I dont know when to unsubscrive. So what happened was when I clicked 'add to cart' on the first item, it worked fine, only that item was showing a loader. But then when I clicked on another item, both, the first and the second were showing loaders, becuase the first and the second were now subscribed to the global `cartLoading` state and the first never unsubscribed.

I've also tried the following code, but with this, no loader was shown:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [unsubscribe, setUnsubscribe] = useState(null);

  const onSubmit = (e, variantToken) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const subscribeToCartLoadingState = () => {
      let loading = store.getState().cart.cartLoading;
      setLoading(loading);
    };

    setUnsubscribe(store.subscribe(subscribeToCartLoadingState));

    addProductToCart(
      {
        prodToken: variantToken,
        cartProdQuantity: 1,
      },
      cartToken
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(unsubscribe);

    if (!cartLoading && unsubscribe) unsubscribe();
  }, [cartLoading]);
```

and then the button in my jsx:

```
!loading ? (
           { <button
              type="button"
              onClick={(e) => onSubmit(e, product.variants[0].variantToken)}
              className="btn waves-effect blue"
            >
              Add to cart
            </button>
          ) : (
            <MiniSpinner />
          )}
```

Any workaroundsd on this? Is may only option to make the backend requests locally?

P.s. if you have a better title for this question, feel free to edit.

Comment: Seems like this use case would fit the typical flow where you'd use `mapStateToProps` when you connect your component to the store. Is there a reason you're not doing that?

Comment: I'm doing it @nick. `cart.cartLoading`  is a prop from `mapStateToProps`

Comment: Can you show that part of your code? I'd expect you to be mapping in `cart.cartLoading` to this component and then you wouldn't need to "subscribe"

Comment: this is a link to sandbox. Note the code wont work there since some dependencies are not installed. @Nick https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-fog-0uvvf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think this can be done with some combination of `useEffect` and local state, but I suspect you'll make your life easier by refactoring your redux state to specify which item(s) are loading. For example, `cartLoading` could be an array (or `Set`) that tracks exactly which items are being loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, I think you'll have the best luck all around if you refactor your redux state to specify which items are specifically loading. Then you don't really have to worry about reconciling global and local state.

If you are intent on using your current state setup, I think the following might work without the `subscribe` functions that you created. Basically you can set the local `loading` state to `true` when you dispatch the action. Since you have `cartLoading` maaped in from redux, you just need an effect that will run when that changes and flip the local `loading` state back to `false`.

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const onSubmit = (e, variantToken) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);
  addProductToCart(
    {
      prodToken: variantToken,
      cartProdQuantity: 1,
    },
    cartToken
  );
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (!cartLoading && loading) setLoading(false);
}, [cartLoading]);
```

Comment: It looks good I will try it out next week after Shabbat thank you for your time will let you know

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use:

https://github.com/RisingStack/react-easy-state

or

https://github.com/ctrlplusb/easy-peasy

they can manage both global and local stores.